# JavaScriptException while trying to set XML Text value in TextArea using Selenium and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium

```
String xmlString = "<xml version ="1.0">"
.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+ xmlString + "';", TextAreawebElement);
```

This `executeScript` function fails and throws an exception when the XML string is passed, but when some single line text line text like 'YYYY' is used, the above statements execute fine without exceptions.

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because you have double quotes "inside" double quotes

```
String xmlString = "<xml version ="1.0">"
                   ^              ^   ^ ^
```

The parser reads that as

```
"<xml version ="  # string
1.0  # huh?
">"  # another string
```

As you did in your second line, substitute single quotes as needed to correctly nest:

```
String xmlString = '<xml version ="1.0">'
```